# How to tell YouTube that a livestream is a 360 video?

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

We are successfully streaming video to YouTube already. However we don't know how to create the livestreams for a 360 video via the API:

My guess is that we miss some documentation about how to tell YouTube that a video stream needs to be played back in a 360 video player. We are using this code snippet to generate the liveStreams resource:

```
    NSDictionary *stream = @{@"snippet": @{@"title": broadcast.title ? broadcast.title : @"mimoLive Livestream"},
                         @"cdn": @{@"resolution": resolution,
                                   @"frameRate": framerate,
                                   @"ingestionType": @"rtmp"}};
```

Is there a (un)documented key we need to add here?

Refering to YouTube API:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams

(BTW: Facebook recently added the option is_spherical to their API to make this work)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **contentDetails.Projection** field to **360** when creating a new broadcast object. It is set to **rectangular** by default. This is documented under https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts